# PATH configuration no effect

Tags: linux-mint, path

I have a question regarding the PATH variable and ways to configure it.

The question stems from the fact that the installation of a software package am dealing with comes with a bash script which is responsible to configure the PATH.

That script fails to do so,and this is where I take over, and try to do that manually.

I have tried some methods like:

```
PATH=$PATH:~/opt/bin           # or
PATH=~/opt/bin:$PATH           # or
export PATH=~/opt/bin:$PATH    # or
export PATH=$PATH:~/opt/bin    # or
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/bin     # or
PATH=$PATH:/opt/bin            # and
export PATH
```

then I run:

```
echo $PATH
```

to see the effect, but nothing appears to be changed.

I do all that in a Linux mint partition.

My question is if is there anything else that I need to do before trying to change the PATH in order for any change to take effect?Or is simply the way am approaching the problem ineffective?

Is there any other way to add variables in the PATH (any kind of software or similar?)

George

Comment: Which terminal or console are you using to execute the commands?

Comment: "Nothing appears to be changed" - in what way? What do you expect the effect to be? How are you testing it? Also, are you sure the correct additional path is `/opt/bin` rather than `/opt/<name of software>/bin`?

Comment: @BinaryZebra am using the normal terminal.

Comment: @RealSkeptic When I say "Nothing appears to be changed" I mean that there is no addition to the PATH after hitting echo $PATH (this is how I test it).The opt/bin is used only for illustration purposes (sorry for the confusion)

Comment: What shell are you using?  a bourne-like shell (sh, bash, ash, dash, ksh, zsh etc) or a c shell (such as csh or, tcsh)?  The commands you used should work with a bourne shell (unless PATH has been set readonly, but an error message will tell you that if that's the case), but for csh you need to do something like `set PATH="$PATH:/opt/bin"`.  more importantly, if you're using csh, you need to stop that and start using bash or ksh or zsh instead.

Comment: That does not answer my question. Sorry if this is too basic, but we need to be sure you are working inside a terminal. Even [this mint guide](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/100) fail to name it. I mean: in the gui you execute commands (probably Alt-f2 and write `gnome-terminal`). That should open a window where you can type commands. The ["before last" image in this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/25_embedded-terminal.png). We need a terminal (aka console) to retain the value of `PATH`. If the console closes the value is gone.

Comment: @cas thank you for pointing this out for me...how do I get to know which shell am using though...?

Comment: here's one easy way to check: if you run `set` do you see a list of variable names separated from their values by a tab or spaces?  then you're running a csh.  if they're separated by an `=` sign, you're running a bourne-like shell.  alternatively, try `getent passwd $USER` - the last field will indicate your default shell (e.g. `/bin/bash`, `/usr/bin/tcsh`, etc) - but this is not necessarily the same as the shell you're running at the moment.

Comment: @BinaryZebra thanks for coming back...The terminal am using is the one that pops up after hitting Ctrl+Alt+t (is the same after doing Alt-f2 and write gnome-terminal as per your recommendation).Am a bit confused with this "We need a terminal (aka console) to retain the value of PATH. If the console closes the value is gone".Could you please clue me in?

Comment: @cas   I see something like that :    COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W '${COMPREPLY[@]#${sysvdirs[0]}/}' -- "$cur" ))
}
_shells () 
{ 
    local shell rest;
    while read -r shell rest; do
        [[ $shell == /* && $shell == "$cur"* ]] && COMPREPLY+=($shell);
    done 2> /dev/null < /etc/shells
}
_signals () I guess am in bourne-like shell...

Comment: @cas after running getent passwd $USER turns out that my default shell in bash.

Comment: The values in the environment (and PATH is one) are valid as long as one shell remembers that value. One shell starts it all: init. Other shell starts when you login. The user shell reads ~/.bashrc (or ~/.profile) to set PATH to all the rest of shells (commands) that  are started. What that means is that the value of a variable (even an environment variable like PATH) exists as long as one shell remembers it. To try: create an environment variable inside a console (Ctrl-Alt-t is fine) by executing this command: `export MYVALUE="ASimpleTest"` and pressing enter. Do NOT close the window. Read on

Comment: In that same window: write `echo $MYVALUE`. It should print the value you set before. Now, if you close the window and open a new one, that value is gone. If you execute `echo $MYVALUE` nothing will be printed. ..... It may be the reason for you to say that "nothing changed".

Comment: To make PATH changes permanent the value must be changed in a place which will affect the initial shell of your user-name. Are we in the right track?

Comment: @BinaryZebra OK!I had no clue!!!Thanks a lot!Shall I try then to make the changes from a particular "location" let say HOME or similar in order to "take effect"?

Comment: I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The value of PATH is set initially inside the file `/etc/profile`.

It is set both for a "default user" and "root" (do not edit it).
You can read it by executing this command in a terminal:

```
cat /etc/profile
```

However, you want to change the default PATH only for your user (so other users may have a different PATH, and specially the user `root`).

In Mint (and that may be different for different versions of Mint) with a Gnome desktop (create or edit `~/.pam_environment` as follows). Assuming you have a text editor called `gedit`:

```
$ gedit ~/.pam_environment
```

And add (or change) this line:

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/opt/bin
```

write the file, log out, log-in again and the new value of PATH should be in effect.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013725/linux-mint-adding-environment-variables-permanently) helped me to write my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the PATH (or any other environment variable) for a shell process by *running* a script.

If the script modifies (and `exports`) PATH, then the modifications will only affect the environment within the script (and any *subprocess*) but not the parent process.

If you want to modify the PATH within your running shell session, you need to modify it *directly* in this session, eg by `source`ing the script rather than *running* it.

```
$ cat mypath.sh
export PATH=/opt/foo/bin:$PATH
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin
$ ./mypath.sh
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin
$ . ./mypath.sh
$ echo $PATH
/opt/foo/bin:/usr/bin
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering,I wanted to say source the script rather thank running.Sorry about that...